# Extract the values from multiple jsonb columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple jsonb columns and i want to extract data from each column.
I am using postgressql.

Input:-

```
ID  Jsoncol1    Jsoncol2    Jsoncol3    Date
0   {"@class":  "team": {"id":"Captain","dob": [1990, 9, 11]}}  {"@class":  "group": {"id":"Colour","dob": [1990, 9, 11]}}  {"@class":  "person": {"id":"Red","dob": [1990, 9, 11]}]}   13/05/2019
```

Output:-

```
ID  Team    Group   Person  Date
0   Captain Colour  Red 13/05/2019
```

Comment: Your json is not valid: `@class:team:{}`

Answer (score -1):

Without `@class:` (which makes the JSON value invalid) the data could look like that

```
id | jsoncol1                                        | jsoncol2                                        | jsoncol3                                      | mydate    
-: | :---------------------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------------- | :-------------------------------------------- | :---------
 0 | {"team": {"id":"Captain","dob": [1990, 9, 11]}} | {"group": {"id":"Colour","dob": [1990, 9, 11]}} | {"person": {"id":"Red","dob": [1990, 9, 11]}} | 2019-05-13
```

The problem seems to be, extracting the `id` value from the JSON object:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=62bcbf17d06b513734bc4966b507a821)

```
SELECT
    id,
    jsoncol1 -> 'team' ->> 'id' AS team,
    jsoncol2 -> 'group' ->> 'id' AS "group",
    jsoncol3 -> 'person' ->> 'id' AS person,
    mydate
FROM mytable
```

[-> Postgres JSON documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)